# tabs between content divs, first div not activating on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs which I need to navigate between using 2 navigation tabs: Year 1 and Year 2. The navigation works fine when I click on Year 1, "first" div appears, and the same for div "second". My problem is that when the page is first loaded, neither div is active. How do I make it so "first" div is always showing when page is first loaded? I have looked through a number of posts but still can not fix this

i.e. when page is first loaded neither tab is showing until I click on them

[image]

It should look like this on page load:

[image]

Current code:

```css
section {
  padding: 150px 0;
}

header {
  padding: 156px 0 100px;
}

.it-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #4582EC;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.it-icons a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3) rotate(20deg);
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.tu-icon a:hover {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}


.os-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #4582EC;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.os-icons a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3) rotate(20deg);
  background-color: skyblue;
}




.tabs .nav-tabs > li, .tabs .nav-pills > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #4582EC;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li a:hover {
  background: #4582EC;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li.active a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #4582EC;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
}

.service-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.service-box .contents {
  margin-left: 30px;
}



.tab-content {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.service-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.service-box .section-title h3 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.service-box .section-title h3:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #333333;
  height: 1px;
  width: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section id="education" style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row d-flex no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
          <h2 style="text-align: center;"> Education </h2>

          <div class="row">
            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="col-md-8">

              <!--tabs-->
              <div class="tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                  <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a href="#first" data-toggle="tab"> First Year </a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#second" data-toggle="tab"> Second Year </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!--Start single tab content-->
              <div class="tab-content">

                <div class="service-box tab-pane fade in active row" id="first">
                  <div class="contents">

                    <div class="section-title">
                      <br>
                      <h3> First Year</h3>
                      <br>
                    </div>

                   <div class="col-md-8 animate-box">
                      <div class="progress-wrap">
                        <h3>Photoshop</h3>
                        <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                          <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90"
                            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%">
                            <span>90%</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>

                      <div class="progress-wrap ftco-animate">
                        <h3>jQuery</h3>
                        <div class="progress">
                          <div class="progress-bar color-2" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0"
                            aria-valuemax="100" style="width:85%">
                            <span>85%</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--End single tab content-->
                <!--Start single tab content-->
                <div class="service-box tab-pane fade in" id="second">
                  <div class="contents">

                    <div class="section-title">
                      <br>
                      <h3> Second Year</h3>
                      <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 animate-box">
                      <div class="progress-wrap">
                        <h3>Java</h3>
                        <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                          <div class="progress-bar color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90"
                            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%">
                            <span>90%</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>

                      <div class="progress-wrap ftco-animate">
                        <h3>C#</h3>
                        <div class="progress">
                          <div class="progress-bar color-2" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0"
                            aria-valuemax="100" style="width:85%">
                            <span>85%</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--End single tab content-->



              </div>


            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Please show us your CSS/JS code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are using bootstrap JS...

```
$('#education .tabs a:first').tab('show');
```

[Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navs/#tab)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `show` class to your `<div class="service-box tab-pane fade in active row show" id="first">` element to show by default.

Adding the class directly to your element is better than to use code since if the element doesn't exist when the code runs, it will do nothing. If you put your code on the `onLoad` function, you will notice a flicker if your page takes time to load.

Also, active tab has to be changed because the bootstrap places the `active` class on the `a` element and your `active` style is on the `li` tag. You have to place the active style on the `li` tag. I've done that on the code below, on the HTML and in the CSS.

Active class is now as:

```
   .tabs .nav-tabs li a.active {
      color: #fff;
      background: #4582EC;
      border: 2px solid #4582EC;
    }
```

Active class is by default on the following element:

```
<a href="#first" data-toggle="tab" class="active"> First Year </a>
```

Example below:

```css
section {
  padding: 150px 0;
}

header {
  padding: 156px 0 100px;
}

.it-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #4582EC;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.it-icons a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3) rotate(20deg);
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.tu-icon a:hover {
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}


.os-icons a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3.5rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  background-color: #4582EC;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 3.5rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.os-icons a:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3) rotate(20deg);
  background-color: skyblue;
}




.tabs .nav-tabs > li, .tabs .nav-pills > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li a {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
  border-radius: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #4582EC;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li a:hover {
  background: #4582EC;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
}

.tabs .nav-tabs li a.active {
  color: #fff;
  background: #4582EC;
  border: 2px solid #4582EC;
}

.service-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.service-box .contents {
  margin-left: 30px;
}



.tab-content {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.service-box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.service-box .section-title h3 {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 42px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.service-box .section-title h3:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #333333;
  height: 1px;
  width: 55px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<section id="education" style="background-color:whitesmoke;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row d-flex no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-12 mx-auto">
          <h2 style="text-align: center;"> Education </h2>

          <div class="row">
            <br>
            <br>

            <div class="col-md-8">

              <!--tabs-->
              <div class="tabs">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                  <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#first" data-toggle="tab" class="active"> First Year </a>
                  </li>
                  <li role="presentation">
                    <a href="#second" data-toggle="tab"> Second Year </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!--Start single tab content-->
              <div class="tab-content">

                <div class="service-box tab-pane fade in active row show" id="first">
                  <div class="contents">

                    <div class="section-title">
                      <br>
                      <h3> First Year</h3>
                      <br>
                    </div>

                   <div class="col-md-8 animate-box">
                      <div class="progress-wrap">
                        <h3>Photoshop</h3>
                        <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                          <div class="progress-bar  color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90"
                            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%">
                            <span>90%</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>

                      <div class="progress-wrap ftco-animate">
                        <h3>jQuery</h3>
                        <div class="progress">
                          <div class="progress-bar color-2" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0"
                            aria-valuemax="100" style="width:85%">
                            <span>85%</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--End single tab content-->
                <!--Start single tab content-->
                <div class="service-box tab-pane fade in" id="second">
                  <div class="contents">

                    <div class="section-title">
                      <br>
                      <h3> Second Year</h3>
                      <br>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8 animate-box">
                      <div class="progress-wrap">
                        <h3>Java</h3>
                        <div class="progress" style="width: 100%;">
                          <div class="progress-bar color-1" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90"
                            aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:90%">
                            <span>90%</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>

                      <div class="progress-wrap ftco-animate">
                        <h3>C#</h3>
                        <div class="progress">
                          <div class="progress-bar color-2" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="85" aria-valuemin="0"
                            aria-valuemax="100" style="width:85%">
                            <span>85%</span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <br>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!--End single tab content-->



              </div>


            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Hi Diogo, it seems like when I click on Second Year Tab the background color does not change to blue like it should. Could you please fix this for me so when a user selects a tab, the background changes to blue like it should

Comment: @CraigPH I thought that was on purpose because in your code it was not working also. I've fixed that on my answer and edit it. Check if that is what you want